# run python file

Tags: python, file

i dont have any experience in python programming but I get to run python file is there any one  to help me pls 
 here is the file content

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
#!/usr/local/bin/python

"""
Based on: http://wxpsvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/svg/pathdata.py
According to that project, this file is licensed under the LGPL
"""
try:
    from pyparsing import (ParserElement, Literal, Word, CaselessLiteral, 
        Optional, Combine, Forward, ZeroOrMore, nums, oneOf, Group, ParseException, OneOrMore)
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.exit("pyparsing is required")


#ParserElement.enablePackrat()

def Command(char):
    """ Case insensitive but case preserving"""
    return CaselessPreservingLiteral(char)

def Arguments(token):
    return Group(token)


class CaselessPreservingLiteral(CaselessLiteral):
    """ Like CaselessLiteral, but returns the match as found
        instead of as defined.
    """
    def __init__( self, matchString ):
        super(CaselessPreservingLiteral,self).__init__( matchString.upper() )
        self.name = "'%s'" % matchString
        self.errmsg = "Expected " + self.name
        self.myException.msg = self.errmsg

    def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
        test = instring[ loc:loc+self.matchLen ]
        if test.upper() == self.match:
            return loc+self.matchLen, test
        #~ raise ParseException( instring, loc, self.errmsg )
        exc = self.myException
        exc.loc = loc
        exc.pstr = instring
        raise exc   

def Sequence(token):
    """ A sequence of the token"""
    return OneOrMore(token+maybeComma)

digit_sequence = Word(nums)

sign = oneOf("+ -")

def convertToFloat(s, loc, toks):
    try:
        return float(toks[0])
    except:
        raise ParseException(loc, "invalid float format %s"%toks[0])

exponent = CaselessLiteral("e")+Optional(sign)+Word(nums)

#note that almost all these fields are optional, 
#and this can match almost anything. We rely on Pythons built-in
#float() function to clear out invalid values - loosely matching like this
#speeds up parsing quite a lot
floatingPointConstant = Combine(
    Optional(sign) + 
    Optional(Word(nums)) + 
    Optional(Literal(".") + Optional(Word(nums)))+
    Optional(exponent)
)

floatingPointConstant.setParseAction(convertToFloat)

number = floatingPointConstant

#same as FP constant but don't allow a - sign
nonnegativeNumber = Combine(
    Optional(Word(nums)) + 
    Optional(Literal(".") + Optional(Word(nums)))+
    Optional(exponent)
)
nonnegativeNumber.setParseAction(convertToFloat)

coordinate = number

#comma or whitespace can seperate values all over the place in SVG
maybeComma = Optional(Literal(',')).suppress()

coordinateSequence = Sequence(coordinate)

coordinatePair = (coordinate + maybeComma + coordinate).setParseAction(lambda t: tuple(t))
coordinatePairSequence = Sequence(coordinatePair)

coordinatePairPair = coordinatePair + maybeComma + coordinatePair
coordinatePairPairSequence = Sequence(Group(coordinatePairPair))

coordinatePairTriple = coordinatePair + maybeComma + coordinatePair + maybeComma + coordinatePair
coordinatePairTripleSequence = Sequence(Group(coordinatePairTriple))

#commands
lineTo = Group(Command("L") + Arguments(coordinatePairSequence))
curve = Group(Command("C") + Arguments(coordinatePairSequence))

moveTo = Group(Command("M") + Arguments(coordinatePairSequence))

closePath = Group(Command("Z")).setParseAction(lambda t: ('Z', (None,)))

flag = oneOf("1 0").setParseAction(lambda t: bool(int((t[0]))))

arcRadius = (
    nonnegativeNumber + maybeComma + #rx
    nonnegativeNumber #ry
).setParseAction(lambda t: tuple(t))

arcFlags = (flag + maybeComma + flag).setParseAction(lambda t: tuple(t))

ellipticalArcArgument = Group(
    arcRadius + maybeComma + #rx, ry
    number + maybeComma +#rotation
    arcFlags + #large-arc-flag, sweep-flag
    coordinatePair #(x,y)
)

ellipticalArc = Group(Command("A") + Arguments(Sequence(ellipticalArcArgument)))

smoothQuadraticBezierCurveto = Group(Command("T") + Arguments(coordinatePairSequence))

quadraticBezierCurveto = Group(Command("Q") + Arguments(coordinatePairPairSequence))

smoothCurve = Group(Command("S") + Arguments(coordinatePairPairSequence))

#curve = Group(Command("C") + Arguments(coordinatePairTripleSequence))

horizontalLine = Group(Command("H") + Arguments(coordinateSequence))
verticalLine = Group(Command("V") + Arguments(coordinateSequence))

drawToCommand = (
    lineTo | moveTo | closePath | ellipticalArc | smoothQuadraticBezierCurveto |
    quadraticBezierCurveto | smoothCurve | curve | horizontalLine | verticalLine
    )

#~ number.debug = True
moveToDrawToCommands = moveTo + ZeroOrMore(drawToCommand)

path = ZeroOrMore(moveToDrawToCommands)
path.keepTabs = True

def get_points(d):
    commands = path.parseString(d)
    points = []
    currentset = None
    for command in commands:
        if command[0] == 'M':
            currentset = []
            points.append(currentset)
            currentset.append(command[1][-1])
        elif command[0] == 'L':
            currentset.extend(command[1])
        elif command[0] == 'C':
            currentset.extend(command[1])
    return points

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print path.parseString("M 242.96145,653.59282 L 244.83646,650.1553 L 247.02397,649.8428 L 247.33647,650.62405 L 245.30521,653.59282 L 242.96145,653.59282 z M 252.80525,649.99905 L 258.74278,652.49906 L 260.77404,652.18656 L 262.33654,648.43654 L 261.71154,645.15528 L 257.64902,644.68653 L 253.74275,646.40528 L 252.80525,649.99905 z M 282.49289,659.6866 L 286.08665,664.99912 L 288.43041,664.68662 L 289.52417,664.21787 L 290.93042,665.46787 L 294.52419,665.31162 L 295.4617,663.90537 L 292.64918,662.18661 L 290.77417,658.59284 L 288.74291,655.15533 L 283.11789,657.96784 L 282.49289,659.6866 z M 302.02423,668.28039 L 303.27423,666.40538 L 307.8055,667.34288 L 308.43051,666.87413 L 314.36803,667.49913 L 314.05553,668.74914 L 311.55552,670.15539 L 307.33675,669.84289 L 302.02423,668.28039 z M 307.1805,673.28041 L 309.05551,677.03043 L 312.02427,675.93667 L 312.33677,674.37416 L 310.77427,672.3429 L 307.1805,672.0304 L 307.1805,673.28041 z M 313.89928,672.18665 L 316.08679,669.37414 L 320.61806,671.7179 L 324.83683,672.81166 L 329.0556,675.46792 L 329.0556,677.34293 L 325.61809,679.06169 L 320.93056,679.99919 L 318.5868,678.59293 L 313.89928,672.18665 z M 329.99311,687.18672 L 331.55561,685.93672 L 334.83688,687.49923 L 342.18066,690.93674 L 345.46193,692.968 L 347.02443,695.31176 L 348.89944,699.53053 L 352.80571,702.03054 L 352.49321,703.28055 L 348.74319,706.40556 L 344.68067,707.81182 L 343.27442,707.18682 L 340.30565,708.90557 L 337.96189,712.03059 L 335.77438,714.8431 L 334.05562,714.68685 L 330.61811,712.18684 L 330.30561,707.81182 L 330.93061,705.46806 L 329.3681,699.99928 L 327.33684,698.28052 L 327.18059,695.78051 L 329.3681,694.84301 L 331.39936,691.87425 L 331.86811,690.93674 L 330.30561,689.21798 L 329.99311,687.18672 z ")
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: is `<<<<<...` part of your file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: type `python` at your shell. It should start python. If it doesn't, you'll need to install the python interpreter supporting runtime system. I'm sure there are simple tutorials for your platform: "Install python [your operating system name]" into Google.

If `python` started a python interpreter, feel free to exit it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

Type `which python` into your shell. It should look something like: `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/local/bin/python`. Put whatever it returned into the first line of your file. (Replacing the `/usr/local/bin/python` if it is something else. Keep the `#!`, that's how the operating system knows it is an interpreted file.)

Then make sure this file is set executable: `chmod 755 <filename>` or `chmod 533 <filename>` or whatever modes would be most appropriate in your environment.

Finally, you can run the file: `./<filename>` or `/path/to/filename`.

Answer (score 2):

Install python.

From the command line, type:

```
python <your_file_name>
```

to execute it.

Comment: install python 2.7 since that snippet doesn't look like python 3

Answer (score 1):

Download python at http://www.python.org/download/. Then you can open IDLE from your program list and paste the code in. Then there is an option to run the code. This is the easiest way, but the best way is to open your cli (acessories>cmd on Windows, Utilities/Terminal in OS X) and then cd to your directory a la "cd Desktop" then run "python myfile.py".

Also from the looks of the file, you'll need the library at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/ installed.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

If you are install python already, so have 2 ways:

1.IDLE: go to Run, and Run module, or F5 for shortly.

2.text editor and command prompt: type your file's directory in command prompt, like this

```
C:\Users\Super>D:
D:>cd mycode
D:\mycode>python "your python file name".py
```

So how it is.